# run WCF service vb on IIS express display error when open web config

Tags: vb.net, wcf, iis, web-config, publish

HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found

The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Most likely causes:
•It is possible that a handler mapping is missing. By default, the static file handler processes all content.
•The feature you are trying to use may not be installed.
•The appropriate MIME map is not enabled for the Web site or application. (Warning: Do not create a MIME map for content that users should not download, such as .ASPX pages or .config files.)
•If ASP.NET is not installed.

[ISS run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8A6s.png)

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to Handler mapping, you need the svc-integrated mapping for the site, in order to make sure this mapping appears you can can try to go to **control panel -> turn windows features on or off -> .NET Framework 4.7 Advanced Services (or equiv .net ver) -> WCF Services -> HTTP Activation**

[image]